# Is "considered" a linking verb? Considered + adj or considerably + adj?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

I'm confused by these two sentences. I don't know if they're both grammatically correct.

1. They have produced a new solar panel that is **considerably more innovative** than any other of its kind.
2. They have produced a new solar panel that is **considered more innovative** than any other of its kind.

Comment: The ["linking verb"](https://www.quia.com/jg/2584186list.html) here is ***IS***, which forms / identifies the relationship between the solar panel and how it's rated / considered by pundits. The actual word ***considered*** (= ***thought to be***) is completely optional here. All it really does is perhaps "downplay" the rating "innovative" to the status of mere ***opinion***, rather than being an established ***fact***.

Comment: ***considerably** more innovative = **very much** more innovative, **considered** more innovative = **thought to be** more innovative*

Comment: In terms of whether "consider" can take predicative complements, then yes, it is a so-called linking verb: "Ed was considered a fool" / "They considered Ed a fool".

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct technically but they mean something slightly different with the wording used.

The first sentence is more direct, you are saying that without a doubt it is “considerably” better than others.

The second sentence you are saying that people think (considered) it is better.

Considerably + adj is correct. Considered would be a linking verb. Considerably is used to describe something, considered is used to show what you’re doing or what someone has done.